# How to add field in field

Tags: 7, entities, media

I have a content type with text field (unlimited). Text field is limited to 250 chars and will be used to put names inside
User can choose as many fields as they want depending on how many names they have for this node.

What i would like to do is to let users upload image next to text field.. if they chose 15 text fields, then they can also upload 15 images, but each image connected to its text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I've been using [Field Collections](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) for this use case. It allows you to make groupings of fields (which, for those in the know, are actually entities themselves) which you then attach to a content type.

The only downside I've noticed with this module is that it does require some knowledge of how entities work if you're going to work with Field Collections on a programmatic level, but from a site builder perspective, I think it might fit your use case nicely.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the [Double field](http://drupal.org/project/double_field) module.

> Double field is a small module written to provide extensions to Drupal's core Fields. By this module you can divide your fields into two seporate parts. For the moment it includes the following sub-widget types:
>
> - Textfield
> - Select list
> - Single checkbox
> - Textarea Consequently, in all there are 4 x 4 = 16 widget types.

Currently it is not supporting file upload. However, you can make this as support request in that module's issue queue.

Comment: I tried both modules a bit and they are close to what i need, Field Collection being able to upload images etc. It looks a bit strange when you make content tho as it is not clear which text field aligns with which image field. Best solution would be that when you when you enter something in text field you have add image button next to it. When adding new text field, same thing again. Right now it looks like they are not connected at all, you can add for example 3 text fields and 25 image fields.